# Including httponly in cookies

Tags: php

Before this gets taken down as a duplicate question, I want to say that I have spent quite some time trying to find the appropriate solutions but came up short.

So I have this .php file:

```
<?php



    $username = $_POST["id"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"]; 

saveLogin($username, $password);

echo "Welcome to our App " . $username;

echo "<p> </p>";




echo "Enter the sample config file to be view";

echo "<form name='view form' method='post' action='Deleteme.php'> ";
echo "<tr> <td>Filename (e.g. sampleconfig.dat):</td> ";
echo "<td><input name='configdata' type='text' size='50'></td> </tr>";

echo "<tr> <td colspan='2' align='center'><input name='btnsubmit' type='submit' value='Submit'></td> </tr>";
echo "</table> </form>";


function saveLogin($id, $pass){
   $data = $id . ',' . $pass;

   setcookie ("userdata", $data);
}


?>
```

My question is what and where do I incorporate the httponly portion to the cookie?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm more worried about the way you make cookies. Never ever store passwords in cookies.

Comment: This was part of a program for an assignment in which we need to find the vulnerabilities. I thought it didn't seem appropriate to store them in cookies. Sessions would be the best bet, correct?

Comment: in that case, alright.. But it's never safe to store passwords in cookies or sessions, even if it's not an assignment.

Comment: Oh ok, that's really good to know! So what's the best way to store them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setcookie("userdata", $data, 0, '/', '.example.com', FALSE, TRUE);
```

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)